# How to separate form with horizontal line

Tags: html, css

in my html page I have div with css:

```
padding: 0px;
color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
background: none repeat scroll 0% 0% rgb(255, 255, 255);
position: relative;
overflow: visible;
```

in this div I have form  and horizontal line:

```
<hr color="#424242" size="2">
```

How can I add this this line after form ? his example work on bigger display but when I see my page on the phone line is next to div

Comment: Please post a complete example page or its URL, so that the problem can actually be seen. For example, how does the `div` relate to the question at all? Both a `form` element and an `hr` element occupy the available width by default, so you must have some code that causes a different rendering.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you have a special reason to use presentational and nonstandard markup like `<hr color="#424242" size="2">`, omit this element and use CSS instead to draw a bottom border on the `form` element:

```
form {
  border-bottom: solid #424242 2px;
}
```

If desired, add some `padding-bottom` and/or `margin-bottom` to this rule, to create vertical spacing before and/or after the line, respectively.

If you need to use the markup, see my comment to the question. But whatever the cause of the problem might be, the CSS approach should avoid it, since at attaches the horizontal line to the `form` element.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the CSS:

```
clear: both;
```

To make a div clear (or go under) another element.

Is this what you mean?

Answer (score -1):

```
hr {
border-bottom: 1px solid #424242;
clear: both;
display: block;
margin-bottom: 10px;
padding-top: 10px;
width: 100%;

}
```

Comment: Why are you abusing a `div` when the `hr` element exists to do precisely this?